# Route [/forum?filter=me] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i want to send filter request to show only my discussions 
it's my route

Route::resource('/forum','ForumsController');

```
 <div class="list-group-item">
 <a href="{{route('/forum?filter=me')}}" style="text-decoration: none;">My Discussions</a>

 </div>
```

its my ForumController

```
     switch (request('filter'))
    {
        case 'me':

       $discussions =    Discussion::where('user_id',Auth::id())->paginate(3);


    }
```

Comment: You're declaring the `/forum` route to be a resource but you're not using it as a resource, you need to review the documentation to determine what the best strategy is for you.

Comment: how to make another route to send link with that route?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing read the documentation

Comment: check my answer bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to send link :)

```
 <a href="{{route('forum.index',['filter'=>'me'])}}" style="text-decoration: none">Home</a>
```

This make the route like below:-

```
  http://localhost/forum/public/forum?filter=me
```

Answer (score 0):

If you user Route::resource function, it has default route name .

```html
Route web.php
Route::resource('/forum','ForumsController');

View.php
<div class="list-group-item">
  <a href="{{route('forum.index')}}" style="text-decoration: none;">My Discussions</a>
</div>

Controller.php
public function index(Request $request){
    switch ($request->filter){
        case 'me':
          $discussions = Discussion::where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(3);
    }
    
    return view('View.php', compact('discussions'));
}
```

Comment: but how i make route on my discussion buttion ?

Comment: i dont get your question, do you mean call route link in button? just exactly what you did, use {{route('forum.index')}}

Comment: i use   <a href="{{route('forum.index',['filter'=>'me'])}}" this works